# what is the best formulation of this idea in english?

Tags: time

I write an essay and I have trouble about this sentence, should i write "electric cars begin replace gasoline and diesel cars." or "electric cars are beginnig replace (replaced ?) gasoline and diesel cars."... or maybe there is some another option ?

Comment: You can write ..."as electric cars begin **to** replace", or "...electric cars are beginning to replace."

Answer (score 0):

You can say "electric cars are beginning to replace gasoline and diesel cars." Neither of your proposals are grammatical.